# Refreshing picturebox image in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am coding a program that edits pictures, I have a picture box where I load a bitmap, the first image loads fine, but if I want to load a second image, the second image won't load and the first one stays, it won't refresh. How can I do to change the image in the picture box using 2 different bitmaps?

I have PictureBox3.Image = bm where bm is a bitmap variable, it loads fine, but then if I press the other button to load another bitmap in PictureBox3 (PictureBox3.Image = bm2), it won't load.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim clr As Integer
    Dim ymax As Integer
    Dim xmax As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim bm As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image
    xmax = bm.Width - 1
    ymax = bm.Height - 1
    For y = 0 To ymax
        For x = 0 To xmax
            With bm.GetPixel(x, y)
                clr = 0.21 * .R + 0.72 * .G + 0.07 * .B
            End With
            bm.SetPixel(x, y, _
            Color.FromArgb(255, clr, clr, clr))
        Next x
    Next y
    PictureBox3.Image = bm
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim clr As Integer
    Dim ymax As Integer
    Dim xmax As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim bm2 As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image
    xmax = bm2.Width - 1
    ymax = bm2.Height - 1
    For y = 0 To ymax
        For x = 0 To xmax
            With bm2.GetPixel(x, y)
                clr = (1 * .R + 1 * .G + 1 * .B) / 3
            End With
            bm2.SetPixel(x, y, _
            Color.FromArgb(255, clr, clr, clr))
        Next x
    Next y
    PictureBox3.Image = bm2
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim bm2 As Bitmap = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
```

Comment: Add some comments on your answer?

Comment: Was this answer the solution you needed?